# Is there a way to coerce R into reading a table with a specific number of columns, so that it fills all columns?

Tags: r, read.table

I'm trying to read [this table](http://physwww.mcmaster.ca/~harris/GCS_table.txt) into R.

I know I can skip the first *x* number of lines to ignore the preamble.

Using this code:

```
read.table("https://www.physics.mcmaster.ca/~harris/GCS_table.txt",
              header = T,
              sep = "\t",
              skip = 36)
```

I get the problem that R puts all the data into one column, and doesn't split it into different columns.

I noticed the column headers, once I've read them into R, seem to be separated by decimal points so I've tried:

```
read.table("https://www.physics.mcmaster.ca/~harris/GCS_table.txt",
              header = F,
              sep = "\t",
              skip = 38)
```

to avoid the header - which is nicer, but it still forces everything into one column.

I've tried every "sep" argument I can think of, with no luck.

Is there a way I can tell R to fill up *x* number of columns? Or is this a problem with my "sep" argument?

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data? I'm pretty sure it has to do with the separator.

Comment: After I run the second chunk, I get [this.](https://imgur.com/a/NTmMEqw)

Comment: Is it possible that you post a sample of the first 3 lines of the text file?

Comment: Oh sure! Sorry, misunderstood that. [Here](https://pastebin.com/6daV0kwm) you go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not exactly sure how many rows/column you expect in the table but you can try either

```
data.table::fread("https://www.physics.mcmaster.ca/~harris/GCS_table.txt",
                   header = TRUE,skip = 36)
```

Or

```
read.table("https://www.physics.mcmaster.ca/~harris/GCS_table.txt",
            header = TRUE,skip = 36, fill = TRUE)
```

Comment: I think this is not right. Looking at the original txt file it seems like it's two dataframes side by side and they are transposed.

Comment: Your second suggestion got me there, thanks! However, I was getting problems when column names had more than 1 word so I had to change `header = TRUE` to `FALSE`, and then `skip = 36` to `38`.